# How to plot and solve this differential equation with maple 12?

Tags: maple, differential-equations

Consider the differential equation `$y^{\prime}=y-2$` with initial condition `$y\left(0\right)=1$`.

a) Use Euler's method with 4 steps of size 0.2 to estimate `$y\left(0.8\right)$`

I know how to do this by hand; however, I have maple 12 installed and was trying to figure out how to do this with Maple, and then make a graph showing each step of the function.  Any suggestions.  I have tried looking on mapleprimes, but it keeps pointing me to functions for newer versions of maplesoft, which I don't have.

I posted this question to use as a model, because I have solved this problem by hand and it will help me edited it for other differential equations.

ps. I hope this is the proper place to ask this question, if not please tell me where would be a better place.

Answer (score 1):

```
restart:

sys := diff(y(x),x) = y(x) - 2;
IC := y(0) = 1;

sol := dsolve({sys,IC}, numeric,
          output = listprocedure,
          method = classical[foreuler], stepsize = 0.2):
yest := eval(y(x),sol):

for i from 1 to 4 do
  yest(0.2*i);
end do;

Peul:=plots:-odeplot(sol,x=0..1):
Peul;

exactsol:=dsolve({sys,IC});
yexact:=eval(y(x),exactsol);

for i from 1 to 4 do
  eval(yexact,x=0.2*i);
end do;

Pexact:=DEtools[DEplot](sys,y(x),x=0..1,[[y(0)=1]]):

plots:-display([Pexact,Peul],color=[green,red]);
```